# ВКонтакте доступ к jQuery из UserJS

Tags: javascript, вконтакте, userjs

Если открыть консоль браузера на странице ВКонтакте, то введя

```
$
```

увидим в выводе объект jQuery, но если внедрить на страницу UserScript:

```
function append() {
    console.log( $ );
};

window.setInterval( append, 1000 );
```

то ровно раз в секунду в консоль будет падать ошибка **undefined**.
В каком пространстве имен искать jQuery и как вообще такое может быть, ведь UserScript исполняется в глобальном контексте и в том же контексте происходит работа, если напрямую вводить команды в консоль ?

Comment: Я удалил свой ответ, поскольку неверно понял причину ошибки. (Проверял на сайте с jQuery, а не на самом вк). Вечером посмотрю подробнее. Оставляю дамп правила из вашего комментария:  

    {"name":"ВК музыка","urlRegex":"^http://vk.com","urlExcludeRegex":"","enabled":true,"preserveDocWrite":true,"css":"","html":"<SCRIPT>\nfunction appendMusicNow() {\n \u0020 \u0020console.log( $ );\n \u0020 \u0020if ( typeof( $ ) == \"undefined\" ) return;\n \u0020 \u0020console.log( \"ok\" );\n};\n\n\nwindow.setInterval( appendMusicNow, 1000 );\n</SCRIPT>","js":"","filters":[]}

Comment: К сожалению, так и не получилось найти решение.

Comment: там $ это не jQuery а

    function $(selector, [startNode]) { [Command Line API] }

соответственно из консоли пишем

    window.my_$=$;
    function append() {
        console.log( window.my_$ );
    };
    
    window.setInterval( append, 1000 );

Comment: Вконтакте нет переменной `window.$`. То, что выводится – это api консоли (https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api). В ФФ похожая штука вроде.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Команды из консоли выполняются в контексте `window` + доступно `API` самого браузера. То, что вы видите, это ссылка на один из методов `API` браузера. Подробно с `API` системой вы можете познакомиться в документации соответствующего браузера.
Сам сайт ВКонтакте не использует в своей работе библиотеку `jQuery`.

Answer (score -1):

Возможно, не подключена `jQuery`, подключите сами:

```
// @require https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js
```